# Solution to a probleme to access to a panel in Java?

Tags: java, swingx

I have implemented a chat application in which the first panel would be displayed is the WelcomePanel, and as the child Panels there is one which have i called LoginPanel where the user must log on to chat, i looked after errors in my code and i have'nt noticed any.
Can you help me?
there is the code(Made in the Eclipse IDE)
Notice:i've made in all the parts the try catch block in order to detect the error and all of them are displayed during the execution of the program

```
private void addEventsForLoginPanel() {
    try {

    loginPanel.getTfNickname().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
            if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {//KeyEvent.VK_ENTER to simulate the click on the button ok
                btOkEvent();
                }
        }

    });}catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error in part 1");
        }

    try {
    loginPanel.getTfPass().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
            if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                btOkEvent();
                }
        }

    });}catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error in part 2");
        }

    try {
    loginPanel.getBtOK().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            btOkEvent();
        }
    });}catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error in part 3");
        }
    try {
    loginPanel.getLbBack_login().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            welcomePanel.setVisible(true);
            signUpPanel.setVisible(false);
            loginPanel.setVisible(false);
            clientPanel.setVisible(false);
            roomPanel.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error in part 4");
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: i have a chat application, the first panel which must be displayed is the welcome panel where we can choose is we want to sign up or log in to the application, the problem occures in the login panel, where error messages are displayed(all the catch blocks)